# what are the steps to replace system.out.println with loggers in java eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

what are the systematic steps to replace system.out.println with loggers.info  in java eclipse project.

Also please mention the steps to add jars, configure log4j etc.

Comment: Please refer to the link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/index.htm you have step by step tutorial for implementing log4j

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/.
If you are using maven then add dependency for log4j.jar, otherwise download jar file and add it to your classpath.